# "He'll have lunch." what exactly does this sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, future-tense

[image]

He will have lunch 12:30 ~ 1:00 according to this sentence.

The anwers are 'b, d' in the question 4. I wonder why can't 'a' be the answer?

a. he'll have lunch.

b. he'll be having lunch.

I think this two sentence has same meaning. but 'a' is wrong. what is difference 'a' and 'b'?
Why is 'a' wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At 12:45 he'll have lunch

This says that at 12:45, the subject will stop what he was doing and start to have his lunch.

> At 12:45 he'll be having lunch

This says that at 12:45 the subject will be engaged in having lunch, he may have just started, he may be nearly done, we don't know.

Looking at the schedule, he'll have lunch at 12:30 and continue until about 1 o'clock, so at 12:45 he will be having lunch.

Comment: +1 Based on this exercise with its simplistic schedule, it seems that at 12:45 he'll be exactly halfway through lunch. But, yes, *he'll have lunch* refers either to *the time he begins lunch* or to *the whole time he has lunch* (*he'll have lunch from 12:30 until 1:00*).

Comment: What do you think of option *c*? Possible?

Comment: option c is correct english, but it doesn't fit the schedule since he begins lunch at 12:30 and it takes about half an hour, he probably wont have finished by 12:45.

Comment: option d) is actually possible since he'll have started lunch but wont have finished yet

Answer (score -1):

"he'll have lunch" simply means that he will eat a meal, but saying "He will have lunch" we are not enrtirely sure that it will happen. Future Simple is used here like a prediction about what may happen in the future.

Here in b, because the author mentions a particular hour: 12:45, we use Future continuous to emphasize the activity ( at this time he will be eating his lunch, he will be during it).

Answer (score -2):

Because the period specified (from 1230 to 1300 hr) is *continuous* period for employees to have lunch. In other words, it is the **future continuous** scene.

So, during that half an hour, he'll **be having** lunch (future continuous). Option *d* is also fine as you are pretty sure that he will have started his lunch.

**Logically**, the option **c** is also possible. Because in that entire paragraph, it's **not** mentioned that when Josh *finishes* his lunch. Say, he starts by 12;35 and finishes by 12;44 pm. You can *certainly* say that at 12;45 pm, *he'll have **finished*** his lunch.

Why 'he'll have lunch' does not fit? Because that is simple future and the time specified is **in between** 1230 to 1300 hr which requires continuity. Had it been 12;30 pm, *"he'll have lunch"* would have been okay.

---

Is this an exercise for the *tenses* in English or some logic? Because if we describe someone's routine that happens **daily**, we use *present tense*.

He ***goes*** to office by 10;30 and comes back by 6;30. He **takes** his lunch at 1400 hr; and so...